# Place TikZ picture over top of text

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, vertical-alignment, diagrams, luatex

I'm designing some letterhead using `LuaLaTeX` (interchangeable with `XeLaTeX` at this point) where I want my signature and name to be drawn like this:

> [image]

The signature is a TikZ drawing, the text is normal type raised by negative `\vspace{}`. However, if you look closely, the text is (naturally) on top of the signature, and I would like to reverse that.

I understand why it is on top, but not what I can do to reverse it because the text is positioned relative to the sizing of the signature.

Because the above MWE example is 3,878 lines, I made a smaller MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{2in}
        \resizebox{2in}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[color=blue](0,0) circle (2);
            \end{tikzpicture}}\par
        \vspace*{-.15in}
        \resizebox{2in}{!}{Minimum Working Example}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

The structure is the same, just a simpler drawing and text. Is there any way to force the blue `TikZ` drawing to display on top of the text below it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\stackon[-5pt]{\resizebox{2in}{!}{Minimum Working Example}}
{\begin{tikzpicture}\draw[color=cyan](0,0) circle (2);\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the third time I've liked one of your stackengine answers, you win, I just downloaded your manual!

Comment: @Ryan Thank you for your vote of confidence.

Comment: It's s really impressive package, and implements a syntax that's much more legible than other solutions to similar problems!

Answer (score 7):

One option is to use `overlay` for the `tikzpicture`; to achieve exact positioning, you could also use the `tikzmark` library to place some marks and then, using `remember picture`, to use those marks to place the `tikzpicture` at the desired location; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{2in}
        \tikzmark{start}\resizebox{2in}{!}{Minimum Working Example}\tikzmark{end}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                \draw[color=blue,line width=3pt] 
                  ( $ (pic cs:start)!0.5!(pic cs:end) + (0cm,2cm) $ ) circle [radius=2cm];
            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update

Since `overlay` is being used, you cannot directly scale the `tikzpicture`; in this case, first box the scaled `tikzpicture` and then place it at the desired location:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{%
\resizebox{2in}{!}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[color=blue,line width=3pt] 
      ( $ (pic cs:start)!0.5!(pic cs:end) + (0cm,2cm) $ ) circle [radius=2cm];
  \end{tikzpicture}}%
}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{4cm}% just for the example

    \begin{minipage}{2in}
        \tikzmark{start}\resizebox{2in}{!}{Minimum Working Example}\tikzmark{end}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=south] at
                  ( $ (pic cs:start)!0.5!(pic cs:end) $ ) {\usebox\mybox};
            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The code needs two or three runs to stabilize.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using `overlay` but couldn't make the alignment and scaling work.