# Apply command on nth character of a word

Tags: macros

How to create a macro with two arguments the first representing the order of character in the word and the second is the word itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\def\ColorNthChar#1#2{....} % color #1 nth char in #2  

% example of use 

\ColorNthChar{3}{examination}

\end{document}
```

And the output will be in the form

[image]

Comment: Can you define "character" can you assume a single token in pdftex, or do you include multi-byte UTF-8 sequences.

Comment: Any character in utf8 sequences with `xetex` or `luatex`.

Comment: Your input has 14 characters, the output has 13 glyphs as the fi builds a ligature. How should that be counted?

Comment: Oh you really should have stated unicode tex that makes nion ascii a lot easier:-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It is supposed that word has no ligature,  I'll change the example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming "character" means "a single character token in input" (so just ASCII with pdftex but Unicode input with xetex or luatex) then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\ColorNthChar#1#2{\xColorNthChar{#1}#2\@empty}
\def\xColorNthChar#1#2{\ifnum\ifx\@empty#21\else#1\fi=1 \textcolor{red}{#2}\expandafter\@gobbletwo
    \else#2\fi\xColorNthChar{\numexpr#1-1\relax}}
\makeatother
% example of use 

\ColorNthChar{3}{classification}  \ColorNthChar{23}{examination}  \ColorNthChar{8}{examination}

\end{document}
```

updated version that checks if the word is too short.

Comment: Thanks David Carlisle, can you add little explanation on how macro work.

Comment: @SalimBou  well it just recursively calls itself until #1 is 1 then sets #2 in red.

Comment: Is there a way to make such macro (Format char and format chars) work with glyphs, accents? as sown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355666/textarabic-highlight-specifc-letters-or-elements-of-text

Comment: @Silva better to ask questions a s a question post not as a comment on an old question. As I say here if you use xelatex or luallatex any uniocde character will work, but not clusters of combining characters.

Comment: @David https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558813/formatting-multiple-characters-and-glyhs-accents-within-the-same-word

Answer (score 13):

A simple implementation in `expl3`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\colornth}{O{red}mm}
 {% #1 = color to use, #2 = position, #3 = word
  % deliver all characters before the chosen position
  \tl_range:nnn { #3 } { 1 } { #2 - 1 }
  % deliver the character in the chosen position with the desired color
  \textcolor{#1}{ \tl_item:nn { #3 } { #2 } }
  % deliver all characters after the chosen position
  \tl_range:nnn { #3 } { #2 + 1 } { -1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\colornth{3}{examination}

\colornth[blue]{-3}{examination}

\end{document}
```

With negative numbers you start counting from the end.

[image]

Just for fun, how to color differently several characters.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\colornth}{O{red}mm}
 {% #1 = color to use, #2 = number, #3 = word
  \tl_range:nnn { #3 } { 1 } { #2 - 1 }
  \textcolor{#1}{ \tl_item:nn { #3 } { #2 } }
  \tl_range:nnn { #3 } { #2 + 1 } { -1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\colorsome}{mm}
 {% #1 = list of chars to color, #2 = word
  % split the given token list
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { } { #2 }
  % with \seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn we have ##1=item number, ##2=item
  \seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \textcolor{ \int_case:nnF { ##1 } { #1 } { . } }{ ##2 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\colornth{3}{examination}

\colornth[blue]{-3}{examination}

\colorsome{{3}{red}{6}{blue!75!red}}{examination}

\end{document}
```

The first argument to `\colorsome` should be a list of pairs `{number}{color}`; since `\int_case:nnF` is fully expandable, at the end we will get either the color for a chosen position, or `.` which denotes the current color.

[image]

Comment: +1. :-) How would you have to change the code so that `\colornth{4}{öäüßÖÄÜ}` might run correctly under pdfLaTeX? (It runs fine under LuaLaTeX.)

Comment: @Mico That would be ***extremely*** tedious.

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,xparse}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\ColorNthChar {mm}
{ \int_zero:N\l_tmpa_int
  \tl_map_inline:nn
   {
    #2
   }
   {
    \int_incr:N\l_tmpa_int
    \int_compare:nNnTF {\l_tmpa_int}={#1}
     {
       \textcolor{red}{##1}
     }
     {
       ##1
     }
   }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff    
% example of use

% example of use

\ColorNthChar{3}{examination}
\ColorNthChar{23}{examination}
\ColorNthChar{8}{examination}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. How would you have to change the code so that `\ColorNthChar{4}{öäüßÖÄÜ}` might run correctly under pdfLaTeX? (It runs fine under LuaLaTeX...)

Answer (score 2):

A little bit late to the game, but here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. The solution is set up to work with non-ASCII-encoded characters such as `öäüßÖÄÜ`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%% set up the Lua function that does the actual work:
\directlua{
```

```lua
function color_nth_char ( n , s )
  local t
  t = unicode.utf8.sub(s,1,n-1) ..
      "\string\\textcolor{red}{" .. unicode.utf8.sub(s,n,n) .. "}" ..
      unicode.utf8.sub(s,n+1) 
  tex.sprint ( t )
end
```

```tex
}
%% set up a LaTeX utility macro that invokes the Lua function:
\newcommand\ColorNthChar[2]{\directlua{color_nth_char(#1,"#2")}}  

\begin{document}
\ColorNthChar{3}{examination}

\ColorNthChar{4}{öäüßÖÄÜ}
\end{document}
```