# Formatting multiple characters and glyphs/accents within the same word

Tags: formatting, accents, characters, text

As an extension to the macros (\FormatChar - \FormatChars - \ColorNthChar - \colorrange)  posted in:

- [Apply command on nth character of a word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529437/apply-command-on-nth-character-of-a-word/529439?noredirect=1#comment1409278_529439)
- [Emphasizing Arabic text characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528341/emphasizing-arabic-text-characters)
- [Apply command on range of characters of a word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529577/apply-command-on-range-of-characters-of-a-word/529602#529602)

Is it possible to modify the above macros in order to:

- Highlight "accents / glyphs" as enquired here [\textarabic highlight specifc letters or elements of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355666/textarabic-highlight-specifc-letters-or-elements-of-text)
  (It is already stated that if you use xelatex or lualatex any unicode character will work, but not clusters of combining characters, just wondering if it can be modified or if there is an alternative): I have attached the image posted in the above link for more emphasis

[image: Coloring glyphs/accents]

- Apply a different type of formatting for a selected number characters within the same word (Mainly the macros were directed towards applying the same type of formatting to multiple characters, yet it may be needed to format a selected number of characters where each character may be needed to have a different formatting: bold underlined character + boxed character with gray highlight....): so that you may be able to select any number of characters in each word and select the type of formatting to be applied to each of the selected characters (bold,colored,italic,underlined,dashed or continous box with colored boundaries, highlight....)

[image: Formatting multiple characters differently within the same word]

Comment: your question is not clear. It always helps if you include a small test file in the question and say what output you want. The problem with combining characters/ligatures  is only a problem if you are accessing characters by number, so in english `different` and select 3rd thing do you want the f (3rd input character) of the ff (3rd output glyph) in English this isn't often an issue but in some languages it affects every word. But if you are selecting characters explicitly it isn't an issue at all `\textbf{di}\textcolor{red}{ffer}\textit{ent}`  selects substrings of that word in three styles

Comment: @David, I added a figure for each point to visually help emphasize my queries, the desired output in (Lualatex, Xelatex: unicode !!). Regarding the formatting of glyphs and accents, I was wondering if this can be acheived in lualatex (unicode fonts). Also, regarding the second query, I beleive the image is quite explanatory.